# icCube - is it possible to add an aggregation type to a calculated member

Tags: mdx, iccube

(I guess it is not possible, but I might be overlooking something simple)

Is it possible to define a calculated member that does some calculation at the lowest level and have the result aggregated.

For example:

In the Builder, you define a member [measures].[calc] as [measures].[amount] X [measures].[count], and have the product only calculated at the lowest level and then its result aggregated over all dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy answer, not yet

Comment: we love sponsor ;-)